# INSERT INTO gets "Oracle SQL Developer Error - column not allowed here"

Tags: sql, oracle

```
Error starting at line : 9 in command -
INSERT INTO movie (uniqueid,title) VALUES (SEQ_UNIQUEID.nextval,title)
Error at Command Line : 9 Column : 65
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00984: column not allowed here
00984. 00000 -  "column not allowed here"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Movie Table Script:

```
CREATE TABLE MOVIE (
UniqueID numeric(10) NOT NULL,
Title varchar(255) NOT NULL,
ReleaseDate date,
Genres varchar(255) CHECK(Genres IN ('action','comedy','drama','fantasy','horror','mystery','romance','thriller','western')),
MovieLength int,
Rating varchar(255),
Distributor varchar(255),
DistributorID int,
WholesalePrice decimal(10,2),
Serial# varchar(255),
Actors varchar(255),
Producers varchar(255),
Directors varchar(255),
Awards varchar(255) CHECK(Awards IN ('ACTOR IN A LEADING ROLE','ACTOR IN A SUPPORTING ROLE','ACTRESS IN A LEADING ROLE','ACTRESS IN A SUPPORTING ROLE','ANIMATED FEATURE FILM','CINEMATOGRAPHY','COSTUME DESIGN','DIRECTING','FILM EDITING','MAKEUP AND HAIRSTYLING','MUSIC','BEST PICTURE','WRITING')),
StatusID int,
MediaType varchar(255) CHECK(MediaType IN ('DVD','VIDEO')),
PRIMARY KEY (UniqueID));

CREATE SEQUENCE seq_UniqueID
MINVALUE 1
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1
CACHE 10;
```

Trying to keep things simple I just wanted to insert the following:

```
INSERT INTO movie (uniqueid,title) VALUES (SEQ_UNIQUEID.nextval,title);
```

All other scripts in order they are separated simply so I could easily troubleshoot them since I am clearly a novice:

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS (
CustomerID numeric(10) NOT NULL,
LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
FirstName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
MI char,
PrimaryPhone# numeric(10),
DateAdded timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (CustomerID)
);
CREATE SEQUENCE seq_CustomerID
MINVALUE 1
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1
CACHE 10;

CREATE TABLE RENTAL (
Transaction# int NOT NULL,
Movies varchar(255) NOT NULL, /*comma delineated list of movie id's*/
CustomerID numeric,
DateAdded timestamp,
PRIMARY KEY (Transaction#),
FOREIGN KEY (CustomerID)REFERENCES CUSTOMERS(CustomerID)
);

CREATE TABLE STATUS (
MovieID numeric(10),
Rented char CHECK(Rented IN ('y','n')),
RentalLength numeric(2),
ReturnDate date,
Late  char CHECK(Late IN ('y','n')),
Rewound  char CHECK(Rewound IN ('y','n')),
Damaged  char CHECK(Damaged IN ('y','n')),
TotalFee decimal(10,2), /*add derived attribute expression*/
LastTransaction# int,
FOREIGN KEY (LastTransaction#) REFERENCES RENTAL(Transaction#),
FOREIGN KEY (MovieID) REFERENCES MOVIE(UniqueID)
);CREATE TABLE FEES (
Late decimal(10,2),
StandardFee decimal(10,2),
Damaged decimal(10,2),
Rewind decimal(10,2),
Tax decimal(10,2)
);
```

I have tried adding the title using ' " and nothing.  Nothing is working for me.  Since it seems like adding a movie can be done when only the movie table script is run I assume the problem must be within one of my other tables.  I am at a loss of how to fix the issue.

Comment: Aside from your immediate issue, your data model is flawed.  The column ACTORS would contain multiple names (a single movie has multiple actors).  This violates the first rule of relational data design, aka First Normal Form.  You should have a child table ACTORS.  And since a given actor can be in multiple movies, creating a many-to-many relationship, you should also have a junction table, with FK to both MOVIES and ACTORS.  Same applies to PRODUCERS, DIRECTORS, and AWARDS.

Comment: Regarding my previous comment about data design, same comments apply to RENTAL.MOVIES,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to actually provide some title, e.g.

```
SQL> INSERT INTO movie (uniqueid,title) VALUES (SEQ_UNIQUEID.nextval,'Godzilla');

1 row created.

SQL>
```

---

**[EDIT]**

I created all tables whose statements you posted, and INSERT still works; therefore, you *did* something wrong, but I can't tell what as you didn't posted that piece of code.

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS
  2  (
  3     CustomerID      NUMERIC (10) NOT NULL,
  4     LastName        VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
  5     FirstName       VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
  6     MI              CHAR,
  7     PrimaryPhone#   NUMERIC (10),
  8     DateAdded       TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  9     PRIMARY KEY (CustomerID)
 10  );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> CREATE SEQUENCE seq_CustomerID MINVALUE 1
  2                                 START WITH 1
  3                                 INCREMENT BY 1
  4                                 CACHE 10;

Sequence created.

SQL>
SQL> CREATE TABLE MOVIE
  2  (
  3     UniqueID         NUMERIC (10) NOT NULL,
  4     Title            VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
  5     ReleaseDate      DATE,
  6     Genres           VARCHAR (255)
  7                        CHECK
  8                           (Genres IN ('action',
  9                                       'comedy',
 10                                       'drama',
 11                                       'fantasy',
 12                                       'horror',
 13                                       'mystery',
 14                                       'romance',
 15                                       'thriller',
 16                                       'western')),
 17     MovieLength      INT,
 18     Rating           VARCHAR (255),
 19     Distributor      VARCHAR (255),
 20     DistributorID    INT,
 21     WholesalePrice   DECIMAL (10, 2),
 22     Serial#          VARCHAR (255),
 23     Actors           VARCHAR (255),
 24     Producers        VARCHAR (255),
 25     Directors        VARCHAR (255),
 26     Awards           VARCHAR (255)
 27                        CHECK
 28                           (Awards IN ('ACTOR IN A LEADING ROLE',
 29                                       'ACTOR IN A SUPPORTING ROLE',
 30                                       'ACTRESS IN A LEADING ROLE',
 31                                       'ACTRESS IN A SUPPORTING ROLE',
 32                                       'ANIMATED FEATURE FILM',
 33                                       'CINEMATOGRAPHY',
 34                                       'COSTUME DESIGN',
 35                                       'DIRECTING',
 36                                       'FILM EDITING',
 37                                       'MAKEUP AND HAIRSTYLING',
 38                                       'MUSIC',
 39                                       'BEST PICTURE',
 40                                       'WRITING')),
 41     StatusID         INT,
 42     MediaType        VARCHAR (255) CHECK (MediaType IN ('DVD', 'VIDEO')),
 43     PRIMARY KEY (UniqueID)
 44  );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> CREATE SEQUENCE seq_UniqueID MINVALUE 1 START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 CACHE 10;

Sequence created.

SQL>
SQL> CREATE TABLE RENTAL
  2  (
  3     Transaction#   INT NOT NULL,
  4     Movies         VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL, /*comma delineated list of movie id's*/
  5     CustomerID     NUMERIC,
  6     DateAdded      TIMESTAMP,
  7     PRIMARY KEY (Transaction#),
  8     FOREIGN KEY (CustomerID) REFERENCES CUSTOMERS (CustomerID)
  9  );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> CREATE TABLE STATUS
  2  (
  3     MovieID            NUMERIC (10),
  4     Rented             CHAR CHECK (Rented IN ('y', 'n')),
  5     RentalLength       NUMERIC (2),
  6     ReturnDate         DATE,
  7     Late               CHAR CHECK (Late IN ('y', 'n')),
  8     Rewound            CHAR CHECK (Rewound IN ('y', 'n')),
  9     Damaged            CHAR CHECK (Damaged IN ('y', 'n')),
 10     TotalFee           DECIMAL (10, 2),    /*add derived attribute expression*/
 11     LastTransaction#   INT,
 12     FOREIGN KEY (LastTransaction#) REFERENCES RENTAL (Transaction#),
 13     FOREIGN KEY (MovieID) REFERENCES MOVIE (UniqueID)
 14  );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> CREATE TABLE FEES
  2  (
  3     Late          DECIMAL (10, 2),
  4     StandardFee   DECIMAL (10, 2),
  5     Damaged       DECIMAL (10, 2),
  6     Rewind        DECIMAL (10, 2),
  7     Tax           DECIMAL (10, 2)
  8  );

Table created.

SQL>
```

Insert:

```
SQL> INSERT INTO movie (uniqueid, title)
  2       VALUES (SEQ_UNIQUEID.NEXTVAL, 'Godzilla');

1 row created.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! So my problem must be somewhere else in my script to setup other tables, this is still not working for me.  I will add everything I have.

Comment: If `title` you're using in INSERT is, actually, a local variable, then **rename it** to e.g. `l_title`. Otherwise, Oracle presumes that you're doing something *wrong* and raises an error.

Comment: I tried the same statement as above but I still got the same error. 

INSERT INTO movie (uniqueid,title) VALUES (SEQ_UNIQUEID.nextval,'Godzilla');

Comment: Hi @MitchellTrafford, what DB version are you on?

Comment: I am using Oracle SQL Dev Version 19.1.0.094.  It is provided by the school and is what the instructor is using so I believe I am stuck with it.

Comment: Regardless of database or SQL Developer version, INSERT I posted *should* work (as demonstrated). Therefore, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: Is there no possibility that my other tables that reference the movie table are effecting the insert?  I don't understand how I could be doing something wrong with copying and pasting exactly what you posted but I am open to more suggestions on what else I could possible be doing wrong.  Clearing I have messed up somewhere.

Comment: Yes, probably you did. I edited the answer, showing that tables got created and that INSERT works. Have a look and then post how you did that. Copy/paste your own SQL*Plus session, just like me.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I am still not entirely sure what went wrong when I tried your code the first time.  However, trying again and confirming my syntax was exactly the same (along with dropping all the tables and sequences and starting fresh) I was able to insert.  Once again thank you for your help and patience.  I will be more thorough in my initial post next time I have a question this was very enlightening.